# Forcing Download from s3 amazon servers

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, amazon-s3

I've been developing a new web application which relies on **Amazon S3** servers as storage system, and **Codeiginter** as the PHP framework.

I need to force the file to download when the link is clicked. The original URL looks like this:

`http://www.our-web.com/download/do/1.jpg`

which generates a temporary signed URL to the actual file on the Amazon S3 servers like this:

`http://main_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/post/1/1.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJEOQKYPKC3CCU5RA&Expires=1305395426&Signature=iuzCdA22gImLK192%2BMAhk8OkAY8%3D`

I need to make the file start downloading from the real Amazon URL it soon as the user clicks the link.

I have two ways now to do so:

1. Use `redirect()` which will open the file not download it; or
2. Alter headers as this code:

   ```
   header('Content-type: application/force-download');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name);
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Expires: 4000');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($generated_file));

   readfile($generated_file);
   ```

Unfortunately, both ways don't help me. The second method causes the download to come from my website and not from directly from Amazon.

How can I force the file to download directly from the Amazon S3 servers, and not from my website?

Comment: use file_get_contents or a cURL to retrive the S3 file then do a passthrough with the headers

Comment: That's what he'd doing with `readfile`.

Comment: correct, but even though I don't want the client to download the file through my website. there must be a better solution to download from another domain.

Comment: Pulling the file through your site is a terrible idea if you're trying to take advantage of cloudfront, which potentially distributes your content to up to 19 edge nodes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You just need to set the correct headers on your files in S3 in order to force the browser to download rather than opening the file. Set these:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.EXT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

You will need to set them when uploading the files to S3. With the [php SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) you'd use [`create_object`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/create_object).

Or you can set these after uploading using ['change_content_type'](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/change_content_type) or by [copying the file to itself](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/copy_object) in S3 and setting the correct headers.

Comment: it's been solved by changing the file meta as this code says:   $opt['meta']['Content-Type'] = 'binary/octet-stream';

Comment: I believe the only thing actually needed is content disposition header. No need to set content type.

Comment: Just changing Content-Type to application/octet-stream when send to S3, did the job! Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Bit late to the party, but often times with a file you don't want to have to decide at storage time how it will be used. You want to be able to store the file once, then in one area possibly embed the file or display in browser, and in another area enable the user to download the same file.

Fortunately you can do that by providing override parameters in the request url. It only works with signed requests, but thankfully you're already doing that.

If you add a parameter like `&request-content-type="application/force-download"` that should do the trick.

Check out the **Request Parameters** section of the S3 GET Object documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

Comment: I believe the correct request parameter is `request-content-disposition=attachment; filename=FILENAME.EXT"`. Your `request-content-type` is working because it's an unknown content type so the browser downloads it by default.

Comment: Brilliant, yes this is what I was after. Would rather not decide this at storage time (particularly since there's thousands of files already in S3 that I don't want to have to modify).

Comment: as of 2019 it's actually `response-content-disposition=attachment;%20FILENAME.EXT`

Comment: Documentation for Luke's comment here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_Example_9

Comment: this work for me, add on presgined request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508783/2175432

Answer (score 11):

The question is about setting this programmatically, but to do so manually through the AWS console:

- Select a file in S3.
- Properties > Metadata > Add more metadata
- Key: Content-Disposition  Value: Attachment
- Save

Comment: Very useful since this answer ranks highly in google searches, and I needed to show a non tech person how to do this on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If your S3 website is behind CloudFront, don't forget to invalidate the file before trying again! That will clear the cached file.

You can get to the invalidation page by going to:

```
Cloudfront -> Distribution Settings -> Invalidation
```

Then enter the path to the file.

It will take some time to invalidate the file. For my file it took 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$s3->getObject()`'s `ResponseContentDisposition` parameter to set the Content Disposition of the response. You can use this to force download a file.

```
$s3->getObject([
  "Bucket" => "example",
  "Key" => "example.txt",
  "ResponseContentDisposition" => 'attachment; filename="example.txt"'
]);
```

Answer (score -5):

You can't tell the browser how to handle a remote file. By redirecting to amazon you're telling the browser to start a new request over there. You don't have any control over that request.

The only solution I can think of is to package the image into a zip file or similar. Of course that adds another (probably annoying) form of complexity.

Comment: the image is just an example, maybe I forget to mention that several files type is allowed specially pdf, and docx. Anyway, thanks for the responce, but I think there is a way to figure this out. Actually many big websites uses external storage system.

Comment: I was not aware of the possibility of setting headers when uploading a file to S3. That is nice to know.

Comment: it is possible, I think amazon has yet has better solutions to provide, the reason why we chosen amazon s3 because it has direct upload using POST directly from browser. thanks for the help anyway