# how do I set content-type when creating a signed url for an object in s3 aws?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create a signed url with a custom content-type, I was trying this:

```
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME, Key: 'myObjectsKey', ContentType: 'image/png'}, function (err, url) {
    console.log(err, url);
});
```

However, this gives the error:

```
{ [UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'ContentType' found in params]
  message: 'Unexpected key \'ContentType\' found in params',
  code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
  time: Thu Dec 18 2014 01:38:19 GMT-0400 (AST) }
```

, which I find strange because the documentation on signing requests here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

states that a signature is made from hashing:

Signature = URL-Encode( Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) ) );

```
StringToSign = HTTP-VERB + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Expires + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;
```

, which allows you to give a content-type.

What's going on?

Comment: have you tried giving the `-` (hyphen) in Contenttype?

Answer (score 19):

This must have been updated because you can now do this, just use `ResponseContentType` rather than `ContentType`. Check out the [GET Object Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html).

```
const params = {
  Bucket: bucket, 
  Key: key, 
  Expires: 60, 
  ResponseContentType: 'image/png'
};

s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
  if (url) callback(null, url);
  else     callback(err, null);
});
```

I tested it even with [Saz files](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/saz-files) and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Content-type is not part of the signed URL. It has to be set on the Object in S3. This can be done on upload (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) or you can Copy the object to itself with the new Content Type (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property).

Comment: Though yes, this is an approach to just upload the document with the file's specified Content-Type (i think it may default to binary/octet-stream, which will default download for clientside embed) you can in fact specify a unique response content type in the presigned URL as mentioned in @cameck solution